# How do I troubleshoot a problem on the route between my machine and Google Cloud API?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a simple application that uses Google Cloud Pub/Sub, and as of a few days ago it has ceased working. Whenever I try to interact with the service (create a topic, subscribe to a topic, etc), I receive a **DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded** error. For example:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
client.create_topic(request={"name": "test_topic"})
```

I have tried:

- Creating new service account credentials
- Lowering security on my Xfinity/Comcast router

The one thing that worked temporarily was a factory reset of the router, but then an hour later it stopped working.

Also, this problem exists across all the Python libraries for Google Cloud.

I am quite unfamiliar with networking so don't even know where to begin to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Full error

```
In [14]: from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
...: client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
...: client.create_topic(request={"name": "test_topic"})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     66         try:
---> 67             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     68         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in __call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
    945                                       wait_for_ready, compression)
--> 946         return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
    947 

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
    848     else:
--> 849         raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
    850 

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
        details = "Deadline Exceeded"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1634864865.356495000","description":"Deadline Exceeded","file":"src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.cc","file_line":81,"grpc_status":4}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DeadlineExceeded                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e6f64ca6ba79> in <module>
      1 from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
      2 client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
----> 3 client.create_topic(request={"name": "test_topic"})

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/_gapic.py in <lambda>(self, *a, **kw)
     38             return staticmethod(functools.wraps(wrapped_fx)(fx))
     39         else:
---> 40             fx = lambda self, *a, **kw: wrapped_fx(self.api, *a, **kw)  # noqa
     41             return functools.wraps(wrapped_fx)(fx)
     42 

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/publisher/client.py in create_topic(self, request, name, retry, timeout, metadata)
    479 
    480         # Send the request.
--> 481         response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
    482 
    483         # Done; return the response.

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    143             kwargs["metadata"] = metadata
    144 
--> 145         return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    146 
    147 

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    284                 self._initial, self._maximum, multiplier=self._multiplier
    285             )
--> 286             return retry_target(
    287                 target,
    288                 self._predicate,

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, deadline, on_error)
    187     for sleep in sleep_generator:
    188         try:
--> 189             return target()
    190 
    191         # pylint: disable=broad-except

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py in func_with_timeout(*args, **kwargs)
    100             """Wrapped function that adds timeout."""
    101             kwargs["timeout"] = self._timeout
--> 102             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    103 
    104         return func_with_timeout

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     67             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     68         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 69             six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
     70 
     71     return error_remapped_callable

~/anaconda3/envs/testvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

EDIT 2:

- Operating system: macOS
- Software firewall: Checked Network settings on my box and the firewall is turned off
- Anti-virus software: None
- Location: Chicago, USA
- Region: Unsure what region my request would go to as it isn't specified

Also, I used my phone as a hotspot and I was able to connect to GCP.

Comment: Post the exact error message. Are you sure that the error is being generated for **create_topic()**? This error makes sense for publishing messages but not for creating or subscribing to topics. Note:  Change your Comcast router back to its original settings as that is not the problem.

Comment: My guess at this point is that a request is being sent to Google and no response comes back or the request and/or response is blocked. Do you have a software firewall or antivirus installed on your system? If yes, turn them off temporarily to verify that they are not the source of the problem. Add details to your question regarding the GCP region, your country, the type of desktop and OS, and anything else that might be informative.

Comment: What does this mean? **I used my phone as a hotspot and I was able to connect to GCP**. Do you mean that you do not see the same problem when using your phone hotspot?

Comment: Yes correct, I did not see a problem, was able to stream messages being generated by a cloud server.

Comment: What does that tell you? You have a problem with your Internet connection or router. Do you have a  firewall enabled on the router?

Comment: As I wrote above, I disabled the firewall on the router already and this did not work

Comment: You can try posting your question in a related stackexchange like https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ since you were able to determine that the issue is coming from your network connection. Also you can try reaching out to your ISP for this to be checked.